# How to pass data from javascript to c# (asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

how i return a value from javascript function to a c# variable (in controller)

and also  i have a multicolum dropdown box in a form , eg book details , when the user makes the selection the book name is set in the dropdown , but when submit is hit i want the code book to be returned(this value is returned by my javascript) for billing purpose , in short for a test box i want to set a display value visible to the user and original value that is returned from the form ?

i read about ajax postback , that you could send data from client to server ??

Answer (score 3):

You're best bet is to set values on appropriately named hidden text inputs. That way, the model can be updated by the post action, which keeps the architecture simple.